# mkusb Casper-rw partition persistance doesn't work

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, mkusb

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 with mkusb and created a Casper-rw partition from another USB live session. I booted from the USB and selected "try..." in the menu. I made some changes like:

- Installed bleach bit;
- Add another language;
- Installed g++.

Unfortunately after restart again nothing persisted...

Comment: 1. It is difficult to re-use a `casper-rw` partition from another USB live drive. Things will usually not be compatible. But it will usually work to re-use the `home` directory from that `casper-rw` partition. You can make that easier by creating a partition with the label `home-rw` and an `ext` file system.

Comment: 2. When you select `Try ...` in the grub menu of a persistent live drive by `mkusb`, you will run a live-only session, you will not activate persistence.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy enough to create a casper-rw file manually:

**Create a casper-rw file:**

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=casper-rw bs=1M count=512

sudo mkfs.ext3 -L casper-rw -F casper-rw
```

If a casper-rw file has been used in one version, it will not work in another.

You also need the word "persistent" in grub.cfg, txt.cfg, syslinux.cfg or text.cfg.